# Find insertion location

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search, mergesort

I have a sorted ArrayList of integers.
Now I have a new integer to insert into the ArrayList.
This new integer has to be inserted at the appropriate position to keep the ArrayList in sorted order.

I can just add the integer and then sort it using Collections.sort(ArrayList), but as the ArrayList is too big, this sort is taking time and I need to insert many times so I don't want to end up sorting multiple times which will eat away my time.

Collections.sort() has O(nlogn) (uses mergeSort).

Can I have anything less time consuming, or can I manually search the position to insert which takes the least time?

Time is high priority.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a different data structure (like a `TreeSet` if possible) since inserting will still cause all trailing elements to be shifted.
You can use `Collections.binarySearch` to find the insertion location though, which returns:

> Returns:
>   the index of the search key, if it is contained in the list; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the list: the index of the first element greater than the key, or list.size() if all elements in the list are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

EDIT:
Example with a `TreeMap`

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> numbers = new TreeMap<>();
private void add(int n) {
    if(numbers.containsKey(n))
        numbers.put(n, numbers.get(n)+1);
    else
        numbers.put(n, 1);
}

private void remove(int n) {
    if(numbers.containsKey(n)) {
        int i = numbers.get(n);
        if(i == 1)
            numbers.remove(n);
        else
            numbers.put(n, i-1);
    }
}
```

Example with a `List`

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
private void add(int n) {
    int idx = Collections.binarySearch(numbers, n);
    if(idx < 0) {
        idx += 1;
        idx *= -1;
    }
    numbers.add(idx, n);
}

private void remove(int n) {
    numbers.remove(n);
}
```

Comment: Also can you explain how i can use binary search. If i have a element and want to know its location i can use binary search. but here i want  to know the location of insertion so i dont understand how i can use this binary search. If i can use that it will be more effective. just dont understand how i can do that

Comment: If the element you search for is not in the list (so the element you're adding) it will return `(-(insertion point) - 1)`.
I still think you'll want a different data structure though, maybe you could use `TreeMap` and have the values be the amount of occurrences of the element?

Comment: You imply if i try to find the non existing element using a TreeSet then it returns me something[Say X]. Now using X i can determine the location of my insertion ?

Comment: If you would use a `TreeSet` (or `TreeMap`) you wouldn't have to find insertion point yourself. I would suggest to go for a `TreeMap` which (since it's a map) holds key-value pairs and then use the value to hold the amount of occurrences of the key (if that makes sense) since your elements are not all unique.

If you however still want to use List then calling `Collections.binarySearch` with an element not in the list will return `(-(insertion point) - 1)`, so add one and multiply with -1 to get insertion point. If the element already exists it gives index of one and you can insert there.

Comment: Collections.binarySearch() made 170 to 95
Will try Tree also and then see the results

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go through the list and add the element at its appropriate position. As your `list` is already sorted new `list` after `insertion` will also be `sorted` and it would be a `O(N)` operation. There is no need to sort the list over and over again.

**EDIT**: - Now there are two things here. One if you need to find the location of the element where it should be inserted into the current list which you can do with `Binary Search`. Actually inserting that element in that location would require all the elements that follow it to move one spot ahead to create space for the inserted element which I think is still more efficient than inserting at back and sorting again.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing, actually, but I'm not sure if we are misreading something in the question...

Comment: Thanks.
That Did quite a good job which is 170 secs to 115 but i need almost to just 5 sec. So anything more efficient. ??

Comment: You can find the location where the element has to be inserted using `binary search` in `O(log N)` complexity

Comment: When i have 100000 elements in the list. Instead of adding the element at the end and then sorting the list to bring the inserted element to it right position, better to search for the location and then insert there. I feel this is better isnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own binary search to estimate position of new element, then insert element in good position.

If you use `binary search` to find location of element and if there is no this element in list, binary search can return last index of searching - it will be estimated index where your element should be. Then you should use Inser Sort to put your element in right position.

EXAMPLE:
LIST(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13) and you want to put 5 into list
Binary Search will return you index about 3, then you can check if `list.get(3)` is bigger or less then your element and use insertion sort in right/left way

Comment: Binary Search can be used to find a existing element in the list.
But here i need to find the location to insert.
So how can i implement binary search ??

Comment: If you use `binary search` to find location of element and if there is no this element in list, binary search can return last index of searching - it will be estimated index where your element should be. Then you should use Inser Sort to put your element in right position.

EXAMPLE:
LIST(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13) and you want to put 5 into list
Binary Search will return you index about 3, then you can check if `list.get(3)` is bigger or less then your element and use insertion sort in right/left way